# composer having problems understanding simple version definition

Tags: php, composer-php

apparently composer is having problems understanding version definitions. after installing composer using the official guide here: https://getcomposer.org/download/ i tried stuff like `composer install` or `composer update`, but every command returns the following error message:

```
Could not parse version constraint >=7.4.*: Invalid version string "7.4.*"
```

- php version: 7.4.28
- composer version: 2.3.5

i did not set up composer for this project, i just want to add a library. usually i just download the php files directly as this is far more efficient, but someone decided this project needs to use composer and now we are in this mess.

does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Refer from [document](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md), `1.4.*` equals to `>=1.4.0.0-dev <1.5.0.0-dev`. So, if you want to use `7.4.*` it is no need for `>=` sign. Or if you use `>=7.4` this means `>=7.4.0.0-dev`. My recommend is just use `7.4.*`.

Comment: @vee so you mean using =7.4.*? so with an equal sign?

Comment: @vee =7.4.* does not work.

Comment: Please read carefully again. I wrote it very clearly what to use.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik just `7.4` works - and from my logical assumption this should also include 7.4.* ;)

Comment: so i need to get php version 7.4 or set the version to 7.4. in the composer file?

also it sounds like a syntax error, but i have no idea where the problem could be.

Comment: 7.4 works indeed. thank you very much. i already had a very low opinion about composer, but holy heck.

Comment: Seems like you got it meanwhile, but yes, that's what i meant:
`"platform": { "php": "7.4" }`